# How to load jar files from web-inf/lib in desired order

Tags: web-inf

I have 2 java files with same name and package structure. One file is from framework team and second file is from customization team. There are 2 jar files framework.jar and  customization.jar. In my web application i want to search class file first in the customization.jar and if not found then search in the framework.jar. i.e customization.jar take the precedence.

How to achieve this ? How to enforce that customization.jar take the precedence.

I have put the 2 jars in web-inf\lib folder. but here there is no way to confirm that customization.jar take precedence.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to acheive this without modifying code. Can i load the jar files from lib folder based on some order like first load customized.jar and then load framework.jar. I think manifest file does not look at lib folder. The manifest file look only at the ear level jar files ie outside of lib folder.